# Can not make non-freefonts installed

Tags: fonts, paths

`Texlive 2013` is installed in `/usr/local/texlive` with a script `install-tl` at `http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html`.

Now I want to use `garamondx` font and installed it as `http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts`suggests. However, after doing this the `garamondx.sty` still can not be found, even though I did `updmap`, `sudo updmap-sys`, etc.

```
$ sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
Detected System: unknown linux
Detected Installation: /usr (installing in /usr/local)
Installing /usr/local/bin/getnonfreefonts ...                            [done]
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.1 ...               [done]
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man1/getnonfreefonts-sys.1 ...           [done]
Installing /usr/local/share/texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...   [done]
Installing /usr/local/share/texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts-sys.man1.pdf ...   [done]
md5sum: eb97b3fe32b28ead5183275ad32699b8 getnonfreefonts ...               [ok]
md5sum: f850d910dd96ee27cecdb3772047d247 getnonfreefonts.1 ...             [ok]
md5sum: fb2b0f7699db8e627d4e26b730e94928 getnonfreefonts-sys.1 ...         [ok]
md5sum: 415b51f7c80a4abe8d0a667a04c9d525 getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...      [ok]
Fixing File Permissions ...                                              [done]
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

1) $ sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a

The fonts are installed in `/usr/local/share/texmf`

2) $ getnonfreefonts-sys -a

! ERROR: The install directory '/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local' is not writable.

So I thought the extra fonts should be installed in the above folder.

3) $  getnonfreefonts -a

! ERROR: The install directory '/home/dao/texmf' is not writable.

Why the HOME folder is not writable?

Comment: Don't run both `updmap` and `udpmap-sys`: use one or the other (probably the latter).  I have no idea why `~/texmf` is not writeable; have you checked its permissions?  But, anyway, didn't "1)" terminate successfully? Can you find `garamondx.sty` using `kpsewhich`?

Comment: @jon kpsewhich `garamondx.sty`  gets nothing. Now I did change the permission of the folder `'/home/dao/texmf` to 777 and installed all fonts, but still not working.

Comment: $  kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL  get
`/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local`. So I think the paths messed up.

Comment: That's the correct value for `TEXMFLOCAL`; `TEXMFHOME` should return `/home/<user>/texmf`.  What should `kpsewhich garamondx.sty` return?  Mine was installed in `TEXMFHOME`, but I didn't use `getnonfreefonts`...

Comment: `kpsewhich garamondx.sty` should return `/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/garamondx/garamondx.sty`. Delete or move to backup any `/home/dao/.texlive2013`. Fonts should not be installing in `/usr/local/share/...` unless the script is confused about your paths. This might happen if, for example, you have a second installation of TeX installed which is a recipe for confusion. Use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to install the fonts. First uninstall whatever you've installed. Then use the system version to install what you need. No need for `updmap/-sys` - the script will take care of it.

Comment: I deleted the `.texlive2013` in Home folder. Now `kpsewhich garamondx.sty` returns `/home/dao/texmf/tex/latex/garamondx/garamondx.sty`. `echo $TEXMFLOCAL` and `echo $TEXMFHOME` also get nothing. How to figure this out?

Comment: Personally, I would uninstall the version in `/home/dao/texmf` and then reinstall using `getnonfreefonts-sys`. You'll have trouble later if you have fonts installed in your personal `texmf` tree. It is OK but only recommended if you can't install them in the local tree. `TEXMFLOCAL`, `TEXMFHOME` are not environmental variables so echoing them is not supposed to return anything.

Comment: I did delete the whole `~/texmf` folder. But the weired thing is: `$ getnonfreefonts-sys -a` gets `! ERROR: The install directory /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local' is not writable. while `$ sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a` gets fonts in `/usr/local/share/texmf` installed.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is a very localized question.